# $X_1,X_2...X_{10}$ are i.i.d $\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. P($X_1>X_2X_3...X_{10})$

Tags: probability

$X_1,X_2...X_{10}$ are i.i.d $\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
We need to find the probability that $X_1>X_2X_3...X_{10}$
My approach:
I tried finding the distribution that $Z=X_2X_3..X_{10}$ follows and then evaluate the following integral to find the probability
$$ \int_0^1 (1-F_{X_{1}}(z))f_Z(z)dz$$
But i am unable to calculate the distribution of Z. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is $\frac  1 2$. This follows from the fact that $(-X_1,-X_2,...,-X_{10})$ has the same distribution as $(X_1,X_2,..,X_{10})$ ( which shows that  $P(X_1>X_2X_3...X_{10})=P(X_1<X_2X_3...X_{10})$ and from the fact that $P(X_1=X_2...X_{10})=0$).